# Javafx Textfield textaligment breaks on font change

Tags: java, css, fonts, alignment, javafx

i try to build a Calculator in JavaFX and i want to dynamicly change the Font size when a certain amount of numbers are on the display,so that it will fit.

This works as i want it to when i set the Text Alignment to the Left. 
But this does infact not work when i use any Text Alignment on the right side,it buggs out.

To be more specific, look at the following pictures:

This is the size default at startup:

http://www7.pic-upload.de/19.02.14/8xjsfv1awtl1.jpg

Then i change the font size:

http://www7.pic-upload.de/19.02.14/9518liqv4ebw.jpg

You can see the alignment is broken....
But the funny part is when you click into the Textfield it will fix itself and will look like this:(no Link because of reputation limitation crap)

www7.pic-upload.de/19.02.14/5e3ddqyt575o.jpg

Is there a workaround? Here are some examples of my code:

GUI.fxml

```
<TextField fx:id="display" alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT" cache="false" editable="false" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="17.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onKeyPressed="#keylistener" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="206.0" promptText="" styleClass="textcustom, rand, backgroundfield" text="" />
```

Application.css

```
.background {
    -fx-background-color: #4682B4;
}
.backgroundfield {
    -fx-background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.button {
    -fx-background-color: #FFF5EE;
}
.textcustom{
     -fx-font: 26px "Serif";
}
.rand{
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: black ;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

The Java Code to change the Font:

```
display.setStyle("-fx-font: 18px Serif;");
```

Comment: Your textfield is not editable. It is hard to tell something without seeing your keylistener.

Comment: I dont think the editable part is the cause, i mean it works when the alignment is on the left side.

Also i dont have it implemented yet, i first tried it with a button and got those results. There is no listener involved exept for the Mouseevent button i press, but the only code it is running is the code i wrote at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug. The workaround can be to use `javafx.scene.control.Label` instead of `TextField`.

Comment: i will give it a bash and will report back